# Torque induced by flow into and out of curved pipe in a single plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, torque

[image: Flow into and out of a pipe]

Considering a tube like in the picture above, some fluid flows in at end "1" and exits at end "2". My book tells me that the resultant torque to the system is

$$ \sum M = m (\vec{d_2} \times \vec{v_2} - \vec{d_1} \times \vec{v_1})$$

where $m$ is the flow rate (kg/s)

and that if end "1" and "2" are in the same plane, the above equation can be written as

$$ \sum M = m (v_2 d_2 - v_1 d_1) $$

I do not understand how to derive this "same plane" equation.

I know that if I keep everything in the x-y plane,

$$\vec{d_2} \times \vec{v_2} = (d_{2i},d_{2j},0) \times (v_{2i},v_{2j},0) = (d_{2i} v_{2j} - d_{2j} v_{2i}) \hat{k}$$

so then

$$ \sum M = m ([d_{2i} v_{2j} - d_{2j} v_{2i}] - [d_{1i} v_{1j} - d_{1j} v_{1i}]) \hat{k}$$

but I don't see where to go from here. I don't even really understand what the same-plane equation is trying to say. Multiplying magnitudes of velocities and distances? Or something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you derived at the end is the more general and correct formula. Reduction to the result in the book requires that $d_1,d_2$ lines be perpendicular to velocities $v_1,v_2$. Remember that $d\times v$ gives the (oriented) area of the parallelogram formed those two vectors.